# Triggering a Cloud Function when a document is added to a Firestore collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to integrate a payment processor using Firestore, SwiftUI and Cloud Functions.

I currently have the function below, which allows me to send Firestore data to the processor and get a return, which is saved to Firestore.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const Iyzipay = require('iyzipay');

const iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
  apiKey: 'sandbox-afXhZPW0MQlE4dCUUlHcEopnMBgXnAZI',
  secretKey: 'sandbox-wbwpzKIiplZxI3hh5ALI4FJyAcZKL6kq',
    uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
});

exports.pay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const docRef = db.collection('requests').doc('zFcWYdeP8wyLprYrc6o1');
  docRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return res.send('Not Found')
      } 
        console.log(doc.data());
        res.send(doc.data());

       const request = {
        locale: Iyzipay.LOCALE.TR,
        conversationId: '123456789',
        price: doc.data(doc).price,
        paidPrice: doc.data(doc).price,
        currency: Iyzipay.CURRENCY.TRY,
        installment: '1',
        basketId: 'B67832',
        paymentChannel: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_CHANNEL.MOBILE_IOS,
        paymentGroup: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_GROUP.LISTING,
        paymentCard: {
            cardHolderName: doc.data(doc).cardHolderName,
            cardNumber: doc.data(doc).cardNumber,
            expireMonth: doc.data(doc).expireMonth,
            expireYear: doc.data(doc).expireYear,
            cvc: doc.data(doc).cvc
        },
        buyer: {
            id: doc.data(doc).uid,
            name: doc.data(doc).name,
            surname: doc.data(doc).surname,
            gsmNumber: doc.data(doc).gsmNumber,
            email: doc.data(doc).email,
            identityNumber: doc.data(doc).identityNumber,
            registrationAddress: doc.data(doc).registrationAddress,
            city: doc.data(doc).city,
            country: doc.data(doc).country,
            zipCode: doc.data(doc).zipCode
        },
        shippingAddress: {
            contactName: doc.data(doc).name,
            city: doc.data(doc).city,
            country: doc.data(doc).country,
            address: doc.data(doc).registrationAddress,
            zipCode: doc.data(doc).zipCode
        },
        billingAddress: {
          contactName: doc.data(doc).name,
          city: doc.data(doc).city,
          country: doc.data(doc).country,
          address: doc.data(doc).registrationAddress,
          zipCode: doc.data(doc).zipCode
        },
        basketItems: [
            {
                id: doc.data(doc).productid,
                name: doc.data(doc).productname,
                category1: doc.data(doc).category1,
                itemType: Iyzipay.BASKET_ITEM_TYPE.PHYSICAL,
                price: doc.data(doc).price
            },
        ]
       }
       iyzipay.payment.create(request, function (err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
        
        db.collection('results').doc(doc.data(doc).uid).set(result);
      }) 
      })
      })
```

My intention is to trigger the function when a document is added to the `"requests"` collection and to fetch that document without having to manually write its id like this:

```
const docRef = db.collection('requests').doc('zFcWYdeP8wyLprYrc6o1');
```

I tried to change `functions.https.onRequest((req, res)` to `functions.firestore.document('/requests/').onCreate((snap, context)`, but then I received:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) do not have the same API as HTTP triggers.  If you want to write a Firestore trigger, you should follow the instructions in the documentation.  I recommend **starting a whole new function**, make it work for a simple case, then port your existing code into it.

Note that Firestore triggers don't have `res` or `req` objects, as there is no direct interaction with a client app.  You can't send a response to the app, because there is no client app that directly invoked it.  The Firestore event is handled asynchronously, after the write completes, and the app has moved on to do other things.